# Google play store list wrong permissions for my app

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

The Google play store lists that I have these "other" permissions:

1. Prevent phone from sleeping.
2. Use accounts on the device.

Below is my total permission set including any 3rd party libraries:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
    android:required="false" />
```

I don't see that I'm asking for those items in the XML declaration. How can I make it so it does not say that about my app?

Comment: See also this blog post: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

Comment: I checked throughly and notice that the google play services library itself is using these permissions.  Its sort of unfair of google to use them and make it look like the app developer is using it. When the permissions come from google the user trust it more. There should be a section called google necessary permissions separate from the developers in my opinion.

Comment: I then found a way around this. I was specifying the entire google play services library when all i needed was admob library.  I changed my dependency to be compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0' and it only uses the admob part of google play services. issue solved.